# Footer text is not rendering

Tags: reactjs, render

My Video Footer is not showing up and i don't know anything wrong with it. Pls help me! Thank you so much! This is my codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-parm-v8jv8?file=/src/Video.js

Comment: In your `App` component, you do not render the footer nor does the footer eveer get exported...
 You should readup on reactJs basics documentation

Answer (score 0):

It seems you dont have anything in your VideoFooter component. You are importing a component that is not created, even in your app component you are not using Video component

Answer (score 0):

??

1. React first renders App.js and that file needs to render all
2. You don't export any "videoFooter"
3. do not name component in camelCase, should be "VideoFooter" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Component name is always start with capital letter.

See the [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

you append your App to render at root. but inside App component you didn't include anywhere to your footer component.

> See:
> https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-davinci-z1k8h?file=/src/App.js